# Variance and Mean Relationship from Simulated Poisson Process with Sampling

Tags: sampling, central-limit-theorem, poisson-process

Background: I have a simple simulation of a sampled thresholded Poisson Process that arrives at a closed form solution but need help with the proof.

In my example, I am simulating 10,000 silicon wafers each containing 500 integrated circuits of area 'A0' (mmsq). Defects land according to a Poisson process with a defect density 'd0' (defects/mmsq). Each integrated circuit calculates a random Poisson variable based on 'A0' and 'd0' and if it returns a value greater than zero, the integrated circuit is deemed a failure (i.e 1 or more defects deems the part as a failure). From here, I compute the mean pass/fail result (wafer yield) for each of the 10,000 wafers. I then compute the grand mean wafer yield of all 10,000 wafers as well as the variance of the wafer yield. Lastly, I repeat this approach for varying combinations of 'A0' and 'd0'.

Interestingly, if I plot Wafer Yield Variance (Y) vs. Wafer Yield Grand Mean (X) with all the combinations of 'A0' and 'd0', it precisely fits the curve:

Y = (1/500)*X*(1-X)

If I change the number of integrated circuits per wafer 'N', the more general fit equation holds:

Y = (1/N)*X*(1-X)

I know this has to do with the fact that this is essentially a sampling distribution but I am not quite able to put the proof together on how to arrive at this fit equation from the basic variance equation:

Var(x) = (1/N)*Sum(x-u)

Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Helpful commentary from this post:
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-a-sample-proportion-p-1-p-n

Basically, this whole simulation is sampling of a proportion where each wafer's yield is a proportion of successes.

The variance of each wafer yield is Var(X/N), where 'X' is a binomial variable. Var(X) = N*p(1-p) so Var(X/N) is p(1-p)/N. The expected value of 'p' is the wafer yield grand mean which gets us to the final relationship I was seeing.